# How to free a Delphi PByte passed to C#?

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, delphi-xe2

I managed to pass a PByte from a Delphi DLL to C# and read the PByte:

```
public void DoSomething(string company, string claimNumber, string language)
{
    var buffersize = 0;
    IntPtr pnt = new IntPtr();

    try
    {
        //Get some data from Delphi dll
        if (DelphiController.DoSomething(ref buffersize, ref pnt))
        {
            byte[] managedArray = new byte[buffersize];
            Marshal.Copy(pnt, managedArray, 0, buffersize);
            //Do something with managedArray...
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        //how to free pnt?
        DelphiController.FreeMemory(pnt, buffersize);
    }
}
```

Delphi function:

```
function DoSomething(var buffersizeArr: integer; var pnt: PByte): Wordbool; stdcall; export;
var
  arrB: Tarray<Byte>;
begin
    //some code
    arrB := TFile.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
    buffersizeArr := length(arrB);
    pnt := @arrB[0];
    //some more code
end;
```

Everything works fine so far and so now I wanted to free up the memory allocated by `pnt`. I tried to pass `pnt` back to the Delphi DLL but I am not able to free the memory and always get a `Invalid Pointer Operation` Exception.

```
function FreeMemory(pnt: Pointer; size: integer): Wordbool; stdcall; export;
var
  p: Pointer;
begin
  try
    FreeMem(pnt, size); //throws invalid pointer exception

    result := true;
  except
    on e:Exception do
    begin
      result := false;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

So what is the correct way to free up memory at this point?

Comment: You should not try to `FreeMem` what you haven't allocated with `GetMem` or `AllocMem`. The pointer returned by your `DoSomething` function is already invalid upon exit (the dynamic byte array is released automatically).

Comment: @OndrejKelle So if I understand you right, nothing to free up and I just can delete my FreeMemory function?

Comment: No, you should not return an invalid pointer. Use GetMem instead of the dynamic array.

Comment: You are telling Delphi to Free the memory allocated by .Net for the IntPtr, not the memory the IntPtr points to....

Comment: @TonyHopkinson No, that's not what he's doing. He's asking Delphi to free a pointer that is no longer valid.

Comment: A managed pointer created by .net. Even if it was still valid, not a good idea...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson `IntPtr pnt = new IntPtr()` is just the same as `IntPtr pnt = IntPtr.Zero`. I think perhaps you aren't understanding what `new IntPtr()` really does.

Comment: Hmm, think I was solving a different problem after a second look. As in freeing the memory allocated by the delphi code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Delphi code is broken. You are returning the address of a dynamic array that is destroyed before the function returns. In other words, your Delphi code returns a pointer to deallocated memory.  Your question should not be "how do I deallocate the memory" but rather you should ask "how do I stop the memory from being deallocated"!

Instead you should do something like this:

```
function DoSomething(var buffersizeArr: integer; var pnt: PByte): Wordbool; stdcall;
var
  arrB: Tarray<Byte>;
begin
  arrB := ...;
  buffersizeArr := Length(arrB);
  pnt := CoTaskMemAlloc(buffersizeArr);
  Move(Pointer(arrB)^, pnt^, buffersizeArr);
  Result := ...;
end;
```

Then you can deallocate the array in your C# code using `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem`.

I have chosen to use `CoTaskMemAlloc` here because this allocates from a shared heap and so you can deallocate from C# easily. You could equally use `LocalAlloc` and then in C# deallocate with `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`. If you allocated in Delphi using `GetMem` then you would also need to export a Delphi function to perform the deallocation, because `GetMem` uses the internal Delphi heap.

Some minor notes:

- The `export` Delphi keyword is ignored and you can remove it.
- There's no point in using `new` with your `IntPtr`. You can write `IntPtr pnt = IntPtr.Zero`.
- If you declare your p/invoke to use `out` parameters instead of `ref` then you don't need to initialise the variables that you pass as parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Everything is working as expected!

Comment: Should be `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem`

Comment: @zig thx, now changed. Another time, do feel free to make the edit yourself! :-)